# SplashScreen skip on Touch event

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android app, it has a Splash Screen that runs for 2500ms.
I want to add the functionality for a User touch screen and skip this Activity.

I could made it with a button, but for pretty objective I just want to add a screen touch listener (Don't know how.)

My SplashScreen:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2500;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashactivity);

    /*
     * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
     * want to show case your app logo / company
     */
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

//Skip this intro
        RelativeLayout root_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_splash);
        root_layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
                return true;
            }
        });
}
}
```

My splashactivity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_screen">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a full screen view named ll_root in R.layout.splashactivity,then in Splash Activity using findViewById and setOnTouchListener for ll_root.

Comment: Gives an id  for root RelativeLayout  in splashactivity layout,and get the root view by finViewById() method,then sets touch listener for the root  view. Please upvote if its helpful for you.

Comment: I did it, but the onTouchListener simply doesn't owrk, updating code for a fix...

Comment: Oh,maybe you should add a view in root RelativeLayout,let this view match_parent,and give it id,then get this view in activity and set listener.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the splash screen. That's so 2007.

Comment: Jajaja, that's a funny answer. I'm agree, but here in Cuba the users like that old fashion behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Add **onTouchListener** on Splash screen layout and call your class on the event.
Hope it will work for you

Thanks..